# Workflow Foundation 4 time problems

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

First of all i apologise if my english is off at times, not my first languaje.

I'm working for a project that uses for its processes windows workflow foundation 4 and asp MVC for the UI, most of the workflows were already done when i got there and I don't have a lot of experience with it... now we've encountered a problem when we have a workflow that calls another workflow, something like this:

process1.xaml
Receive Request ---> get Entity -->for each entity ----// call process2.xaml // -->send response

process2.xaml
receive request--->calc salary--->send response

It all used to work fine but lately when the process2.xaml takes longer than 30 seconds the workflow just aborts and we get this message:

** An error processing the current work item has caused the workflow to abort.  See the inner exception for details. InnerException Message: The transaction has aborted.**

The timeout is set to the default 1 minute and I'm not sure what other values i have to change for the process to keep running. With testing data everything works fine since there aren't a lot of data so the process ends up fast, but as the data increases errors start happening.

Any ideas?

Also, is there a way for me to say to "process1.xaml" to retry calling "process2.xaml" let's say 3 times? then send an error msg if it fails?

Thanx in advance for your time with this.

SVP

Comment: Sounds like `calc salary` is taking too long. You need to determine what dependencies exist - web services, ado.net, etc. You will find your cause there.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is there a way for me to say to "process1.xaml" to retry calling
>   "process2.xaml" let's say 3 times? then send an error msg if it fails?

A solution (in the sequential control-flow style) would be to put the invocation of process 2 into a TryCatch activity to catch the exception and a While activity for repetetive execution. Then, maintain an Exception counter that controls the While and is incremented each time an Exception occurs. If the amount exceeds a given threshold, you can send a user message and abort. Here's an outine in XAML:

```
<While>
  <While.Variables>
    <Variable TypeArguments="Int32" Default="0" Name="exceptionCounter" />
  </While.Variables>
  <While.Condition>[exceptionCounter &lt; 3]</While.Condition>
  <TryCatch>
    <TryCatch.Try>
      <Sequence>
        <!--Call Process 2-->
        <Assign>
            <!--Everything worked fine. Set exceptionCounter to 3 to abort the While-->
        </Assign>
      </Sequence>
    </TryCatch.Try>
    <TryCatch.Catches>
      <Catch TypeArguments="InnerException">
          <If Condition="[exceptionCounter &lt; 3]">
            <If.Then>
              <Assign>
                 <!--Increment Counter-->
              </Assign>
            </If.Then>
            <If.Else>
              <Sequence>
                <!--Send Error Message-->
                <TerminateWorkflow/>
              </Sequence>
            </If.Else>
          </If>
      </Catch>
    </TryCatch.Catches>
  </TryCatch>
</While>
```